# Is this Synchronized Code causing unnecessary thread waiting?

Tags: java, multithreading

We have an application that has a class which holds members that are populated via the database.  Here is a representative example of the situation.

```
private AtomicBoolean data1Initialized = new AtomicBoolean(false);
protected SomeSynchronizedDataStructure<Object> data1 = <initializeit>;

protected final synchronized void initData1() {
    if (data1Initialized.compareAndSet(false, true)){
        // Populate data1 data structure from database
    }
}
public SomeSynchronizedDataStructure<Object> getData1(){
    initData1();
    return data1;
}
```

And we have this same pattern for data1, data2, data3... dataN.  Each dataStructure is not related to the other, they just are in the same class.  This data is accessed across multiple threads.  A few questions about this pattern:

Synchronizing the methods will make it so that threads have to wait for a boolean check across all different `dataN`s, correct?  Which is unnecessary?

Does the data structure need to be synchronized?  The data will not change throughout the life of the application.  I would think that only initalizing it would need to be synchronized and access could happen unsynchronized.

*Most important to me personally*

Could this ever cause a deadlock?  I think no, but I'm not experienced with threads.

Comment: hmm I'm guessing populating data is basically read data, you don't need synchronized unless you change data somehow

Comment: Rule of thumb: if it's not going to be written to during its lifetime, there's no need to synchronize it

Comment: You wouldn't need both "synchronized" and an AtomicBoolean anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Synchronizing the methods will make it so that threads have to wait for a boolean check across all different dataNs, correct?

Correct.

> Which is unnecessary?

Yes, it is unnecessary because the dataNs are unrelated.

> Does the data structure need to be synchronized? The data will not change throughout the life of the application. I would think that only initalizing it would need to be synchronized and access could happen unsynchronized.

Again, correct. BarrySW19's answer gives you the pattern for safely initializing it without synchronizing.

> Most important to me personally
>
> Could this ever cause a deadlock? I think no, but I'm not experienced with threads.

It can't cause a deadlock in and of itself. However, if one of the data init methods invokes something else that is synchronized on another monitor (call it m), and meanwhile some other thread owns m and now tries to init one of the dataNs, that's deadlock.

Answer (score 3):

As you are initialising at class creation time all you need is:

```
public class DataHolder {
    // Note: 'final' is needed to ensure value is committed to memory before DataHolder
    private final SomeSynchronizedDataStructure<Object> data1 = <initializeit>;

    public SomeSynchronizedDataStructure<Object> getData1(){
        return data1;
    }
}
```

Because the "initializeit" code will be run in the class' constructor you know it will be ready by the time you have a class handle available to pass around anyway. E.g.:

```
DataHolder dataHolder = new DataHolder();
// dataHolder has already created the data structure by the time I do...
dataHolder.getData1();
```

If you did want to go with lazy loading you could simply use synchronized:

```
public class DataHolder {
    private SomeSynchronizedDataStructure<Object> data1;

    public synchronized SomeSynchronizedDataStructure<Object> getData1() {
        // synchronized guarantees each thread will see "data1" just as the
        // last thread left it.
        if(data1 == null) {
            data1 = initializeit();
        }
        return data1;
    }
}
```